# UWP Xbox One API

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

I am working on creating some basic Xbox One UWP application.
Can someone provide me with a link to API's that can do Xbox One specific tasks?
Taking a screenshot, seeing user that is active, recording, friends lists. Those kinds of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such APIs to implement your requirement, most of them are controlled by system instead of app.

For the possibilities in UWP on Xbox One, see [UWP on Xbox One samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/samples)

See also [UWP features that aren't yet supported on Xbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt693377)

Reference: [UWP Game Capture on Xbox DirectX or MMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395413/uwp-game-capture-on-xbox-directx-or-mmf)

Comment: Thank you for answering that. This question is outside the scope of the question above, however can you point me in the right direction for creating a UWP game. I know how to write C# logic but C# isn't good for graphical games. So I would assume I would need C++, is there any samples right now that are a mixture of both?

Comment: @BaileyMiller DX or Unity, check [Developing games on Windows 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/games/develop) and [Create a simple Universal Windows Platform (UWP) game with DirectX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--create-your-first-metro-style-directx-game)

Comment: Indeed only retail publishers/developers or Id@Xbox publishers have access to the Xbox Live API which has some of those features